# Declaring again the same command

Tags: macros

I defined a certain command, but now I want to change its definition. I tried to simply change it, but it doesn't compile.

What should I do?

Thank you very much.

EDIT

The former command was

`\newcommand{\dt}{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}`

Then I wanted to change it to

`\newcommand{\dt}{\dot{\gamma}}`

but it didn't work.
Now I tried with

`\renewcommand{\dt}{\dot{\gamma}}`

but I got this message:

> LaTeX Error: \dt undefined.

Comment: Using `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` should work, but we don't see any code here. A `\def\....` should always work, apart from syntax or other errors

Comment: Perhaps `\renewcommand` solves your problem. Please include a minimal working example.showing what you have and what you want if you still need help.

Comment: Please be specific as what you mean by "simply chang[ing]" a command.

Comment: Without an example of “before the cure and after the cure” it's difficult to say.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the comments! I edited the question.

Comment: could you provide a (minimal) example document where the error occurs? For me, it's working:

`\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dt}{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}
\begin{document}
 $\dt$\renewcommand{\dt}{\dot{\gamma}}$\dt$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods:

1. Fresh definition.

   ```
   \newcommand{\dt}{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}
   ```
2. LaTeX's `\renewcommand` requires that the command exists.

   ```
   \renewcommand{\dt}{\dot{\gamma}}
   ```
3. If it is unclear, whether the command is defined, then `\providecommand` can be used to ensure that the macro is defined.

   ```
   \providecommand{\dt}{}
   \renewcommand{\dt}{\frac{a}{b}}
   ```
4. When the macro is assigned to a undefined macro or `\relax`, then `\newcommand` thinks that the macro is undefined and does not complain.

   ```
   \let\dt\relax
   \newcommand{\dt}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t}
   ```
5. The TeX primitive `\def` does not care for a previous definition, it defines and overwrites a previously defined macro.

   ```
   \def\dt{d^t}
   ```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\begin{document}

% 1
\newcommand{\dt}{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}}
\begin{equation}\dt\end{equation}

% 2
\renewcommand{\dt}{\dot{\gamma}}
\begin{equation}\dt\end{equation}

% 3
\providecommand{\dt}{}
\renewcommand{\dt}{\frac{a}{b}}
\begin{equation}\dt\end{equation}

% 4
\let\dt\relax
\newcommand{\dt}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t}
\begin{equation}\dt\end{equation}

% 5
\def\dt{d^t}
\begin{equation}\dt\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Out of 3-5, is there any way preferrable / "nicer" than the others? I have the feeling that the later ways get "dirtier", is that right?

Comment: Thank you very much! But actually I solved my problem just adding two extra brackets, i.e. 
`\newcommand{\dt}{{\dot{\gamma}}}`

Apparently without those extra brackets I had problems when writing something like 
`$ \nabla_\dt$`

Comment: @riddleculous 3 is "pure LaTeX", 5 uses the underlying TeX primitive directly and is shorter to write. It is a matter of taste, which style you prefer.

Comment: @Onil90: this is why you should provide a full example where the error occurred. This is a standard mistake that could have been easily spotted.

Comment: @Onil90 Yes, the additional curly braces makes a subformula, which can be used in subscripts and superscripts. In this case is the horizontal spacing not affected. A subformula is set as `\mathord` in the same way as the "ordinary" `\dot{\gamma}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: thanks. My definition of dirtier was here, that I can make mistakes more easily using def since all other options require explicit thinking that I want to overwrite a command. But I would use something other than `\(re)newcommand` (or the `xparse` equivalent) only when needed, anyway.